# Recommended approach for project-specific keras config?

Tags: keras

My goal is to maintain `keras` config on a per-project basis, e.g. one project prefers the `theano` backend, and another project prefers the `tensorflow` backend.  As a bonus, I would like to share this config with other developers relatively seamlessly.

Here are a few ideas:

1. Can keras config be managed by/within a virtual environment?
2. Should I use something like `dotenv` or `autoenv` to manage some shared environment configuration (via the `KERAS_BACKEND` environment variable)?
3. Should keras be updated to look for a `.keras/keras.json` file in the working tree before using the version in `$HOME`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Can keras config be managed by/within a virtual environment?

The basic config parameters (like backend, floating point precision) are managed in the `$KERAS_HOME/keras.json` file. You could create a `keras.json` per Anaconda/virtual environment and set `KERAS_HOME` to point to a specific file as you load it.

Alternatively, these variables can be set during runtime through Keras backend, which would override the value in the config file:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.set_floatx('float16')
```

Depending on the Keras backend, there are other parameters one can configure. With `tensorflow` backend, for instance, one might want to configure `tf.ConfigProto`. One practical way to do it is during the runtime like:

```
import os 
if os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] == 'tensorflow':
    import tensorflow as tf
    from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.95, allow_growth=True)
    config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
    set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

See [config.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto) for what can be configured.

> 2. Should I use something like `dotenv` or `autoenv` to manage some shared
>      environment configuration (via the `KERAS_BACKEND` environment
>      variable)?

It is definitely not a must, one could live with `os.environ` and get/set methods available in Keras to modify the variables.

> 3. Should keras be updated to look for a `.keras/keras.json` file in the working tree before using the version in `$HOME`?

It is possible to point to a custom location of the `keras.json` config file by changing the `KERAS_HOME` env variable or launching your application like:

```
env KERAS_HOME=<path to custom folder containing keras.json> python keras_app.py
```

Comment: Is it that `KERAS_HOME='./path/to/dir/containing/keras.json'` or `KERAS_HOME='./path/to/keras.json'`? Also does setting `K.set_...()` propagate through all subsequent imports of keras in submodules?

Comment: Path to custom folder containing keras.json (I corrected the response, thanks for pointing out). And, umm, this will be only available starting 2.1.7, here is the PR:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/10183